# Django Nested Serializer not working

Tags: python, django, serialization

I am trying to create a Django nested serializer.

This is my serializer:

```
class GetUsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = NameSerializer(source='user_id')
    birthday = BirthdaySerializer(source='user_id')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_id',
                  'username',
                  'name',
                  'birthday')
```

and the secondary serializers:

```
class BirthdaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Eligibility
        fields = ('dobd',
                  'dobm',
                  'doby',)

class NameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Demographics
        fields = ('firstname',
                  'lastname',)
```

Both the Demographics and Eligibility models have foreign keys for the User model (these foreign keys are both user in the model file - and they are stored in the database as user_id).

What should I put in the source field? Currently I have user_id, which is a secondary id field (not the pk) on the User model, should I be using the pk instead (id)?

Should I pass in the argument many=True to the serializer? There should only be one instance per user.

Also getting:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `firstname` on serializer `NameSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `int` instance.
Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'firstname'.
```

Comment: Please add models definitions too. I am working on similar thing, might help to see difference.

Comment: Is `source` a thing? I don't see it in the docs.